# ReportLab Django Not Rendering Chinese Characters

Tags: python, django, fonts, reportlab

I'm having difficulty making ReportLab render Chinese Characters.  From everything I've looked up people are saying that it is probably a font problem but I've used a lot of different fonts and it doesn't even seem to be using them at all.  The Chinese characters always just come out as black squares.  Below is some sample code of what I have.

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from io import BytesIO

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arial', 'arial.ttf', 'UTF-8'))

buffer = BytesIO()
doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer,
                        rightMargin=inch*0.5,  # 1/2 Inch
                        leftMargin=inch*0.5,  # 1/2 Inch
                        bottomMargin=0,
                        topMargin=inch*0.375,  # 3/8 Inch
                        pagesize=letter)
# Get Styles
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
# Custom Style
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Address', font='Arial', fontSize=8))

elements = []
elements.append(Paragraph(u'6905\u897f\u963f\u79d1\u8857\uff0c\u5927\u53a6\uff03\u5927', styles['Address']))

doc.build(elements)

# Get the value of the BytesIO buffer and write it to the response.
pdf = buffer.getvalue()
buffer.close()
return pdf
```

I'm using an arial.ttf font found on my Ubuntu 12.04 installation in the fonts folder.  I have also tried other fonts installed on this machine and all have exactly the same look even on the numbers and none of the Chinese characters are anything other than black squares.

Am I registering fonts wrong if even the numbers at the beginning aren't printing correctly?   What could be causing the black squares?

Comment: Font has to actually have the characters for the code. Chinese characters are present in VERY few fonts - does ARIAL actually have them? From my experience with reportlab pdf's (i was working with Latvian/Lithuanian/Estonian special characters), it printed squares for special characters that the font did not have. One of the few fonts that worked was Calibri. Now i am not sure that Calibri has the  special characters. What i had to do was - to generate the font file for generating pdf for myself to get it working. There is some online tool for that - if you google for it- i'm sure y'll find it

Comment: The font definitely has Chinese Characters in it.  I am using Arial from Office 2010 and it has all of the character sets.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't contain Chinese characters (unless you're talking about Arial Unicode MS, which is an entirely different beast)(and doesn't contain "all of the character sets", just many of them). Standard Arial does not contain any Chinese characters. If you are using Arial and seeing Chinese characters, it is most likely the result of a font fallback mechanism.

Comment: It is the Arial Unicode MS font, I just renamed it.  You're right it doesn't contain all character sets but I was sure it contained the ones I was looking for. I was able to solve my problem below. Simple typo in my paragraph style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.  Turns out in your ParagraphStyle it needs to be fontName="Arial" not font="Arial" but I did learn some other tricks of getting it to work in other ways below.

```
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Address', fontName='Arial')
```

After doing some digging I've learned a few things that I hope helps someone else in this situation.  When you add the  tags inside of your Paragraph around the Unicode text and set it explicitly to a font it will work.

```
elements.append(Paragraph(u'<font name="Arial">6905\u897f\u963f\u79d1\u8857\uff0c\u5927\u53a6\uff03\u5927</font>', styles['Address']))
```

This fixes the problem at least for Paragraphs with various fonts.
Again this code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the fonts that supports Chinese characters.

In Ubuntu, I choose "AR PL UMing CN" for example.

My code snippets:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
...
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('AR PL UMing CN', 'uming.ttc'))
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

...
styles.add(ParagraphStyle(name='Chinese', fontName='AR PL UMing CN',    fontSize=20))

elements=[]
elements.append(Paragraph("成”, styles['Chinese']))
doc.build(elements)
...
```

I can even change to Chinese editor and type in the character straight off. Hope this helps.