# How to draw a table in Arabic reportlab in Python:

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.7, reportlab

When printing the table in the code below, the Arabic language is displayed as symbols.
Thank you

```
import mysql.connector
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont


doc = SimpleDocTemplate("Ropert_Accont.pdf", pagesize=letter)
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arabic', 'Arial.ttf'))
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()

elements = []

db = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', passwd='', host='localhost', database='users')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM acoonus  WHERE  idus = 1")
result = cursor.fetchall()

dt = [('ت', 'المبلغ', 'تاريخ التسليم', 'الملاحضات')]
for rus in result:
    dt = dt + [rus]

t = Table(dt)
t.setStyle(TableStyle([('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'CENTER'),
                       ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.black),
                       ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.green),
                       ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (0, -1), colors.red),
                       ('VALIGN', (0, -1), (-1, -1), 'MIDDLE'),
                       ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
                       ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.5, colors.black),
                       ('TEXTfont', (0, 0), (-1, -1), "Arabic")
                       
                       ]))

elements.append(t)

doc.build(elements)
```

Comment: Maybe this could be inspirational: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465540/reportlab-django-not-rendering-chinese-characters

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use Arabic in Tables by register Arabic font in style and use it in the table.

All you did is the great code, only thing is missing is add font style with "**FONTNAME**" instead of "**TEXTfont**"

P.S to display Arabic words you should first reverse, check the below code maybe it helps.

```
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

pdf.registerFont(TTFont('Arabic', 'path to the font directory/cairo.ttf'))
tabledata = [
    [get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(u"الاسم")), get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(u"الهاتف"))],
    [get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape(u"تجربة")), "123456789"]
]
t1 = Table(tabledata, 4 * [1.8 * inch], 4 * [0.5 * inch])
t1.setStyle(TableStyle([
    ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (3, 3), "Arabic"),
]))
```

as you see you can revers the litters by this code

```
ar = arabic_reshaper.reshape(u"السلام عليكم")
ar = get_display(ar)
```